# Change OBJECT ATTRIBUTE that it is ATTRIBUTE of an other OBJECT in PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, oop, nested-attributes, python-class

I am trying to implement a structural analysis class and I getting the following error.

The idea is to assign a **CrossSection object** to a **Beam object** and assign the value of Beam.eleTag attribute (integer) also at CrossSection.sectionTag attribute.

I am struggling to make the crossSection object to have the same sectionTag as eleTag.
The sectionTag is not referenced to the object unfortunately.

I have tried to do:

```
class ForceBeamColumn(object):

    def __init__(self, Crv, CrossSection):

        self.Crv = Crv
        self.CrossSection = CrossSection
        
        self.eleTag = None

class ElasticSection(object):
    def __init__(self, Area, Izz, Iyy, J):

        self.Area = Area
        self.Izz = Izz
        self.Iyy = Iyy
        self.J = J

        self.sectionTag = None


Section = ElasticSection(100,200,300,400)

beam0 = ForceBeamColumn("anyCrv", Section )
beam1 = ForceBeamColumn("anyCrv", Section )
beam2 = ForceBeamColumn("anyCrv", Section )

Beam = [beam0, beam1, beam2]

for index,beam in enumerate(Beam):

    beam.eleTag = index
    beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = beam.eleTag

for beam in Beam:
    print("beam.eleTag = " + str( beam.eleTag) )
    print("beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = " + str( beam.CrossSection.sectionTag) )
```

OUTPUT

```
beam.eleTag = 0
beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = 2
beam.eleTag = 1
beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = 2
beam.eleTag = 2
beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = 2
```

As you can see, the CrossSection Tag of the object is updating while I want the CrossSection tag to be referenced to the object.

OUTPUT WANTED

```
beam.eleTag = 0
beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = 0
beam.eleTag = 1
beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = 1
beam.eleTag = 2
beam.CrossSection.sectionTag = 2
```

Comment: You only create one `ElasticSection` object, then you add that single object into three other objects, and mutate the single object. You'd need to make a copy of `Section`, then give a copy to each call to `ForceBeamColumn`, or have `ForceBeamColumn("anyCrv", ElasticSection(100,200,300,400))` three times instead of reusing `Section`.

Comment: thanks! It works perfectly!